# Why do I get error, Invalid command 'PythonHandler'?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, django, mod-python

I'm trying to deploy a Django application, but I've hit a brick wall. On Debian (latest), I've run these commands so far:

```
apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert libapache2-mod-python python-django
```

I've tried adding the module manually in the Apache 2 config files, but to be honest I'm totally lost. It's totally different to Apache version 1 which I used years ago.

```
Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'PythonHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I've added the following to my `sites-available/default` file, between the  tags.

```
    <Location "/">
              SetHandler python-program
              PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
              SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE hellodjango1.settings
              PythonDebug Off
    </Location>
```

Here's what tutorials I've used so far, without much luck:

- [Django | How to use Django with Apache and mod_python | Django Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/)
- [How To Install Django On Debian Etch (Apache2/mod_python)](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-django-on-debian-etch-apache2-mod_python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to manually create the python.load file, weird. Anyway, these two commands fixed it:

```
echo "LoadModule python_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_python.so" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/python.load
ln -s ../mods-available/python.load etc/apache2/mods-enabled/python.load
```

Comment: Hmm, a down-vote. Maybe I will review which answer works best for this question.

Comment: there is missing slash:  etc/apache2/mods-enabled/python.load

Answer (score 5):

Have you enabled mod_python.load in mods-enabled? You can do this by just creating a softlink to the same file in mods-available.

Comment: txwikinger, thanks for the tip - I had to manually create the .load file. Which is odd since I assumed it'd already be there.

Answer (score 5):

more easy way to do it

a2enmod python

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, you need to:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gentoo, define -D PYTHON in /etc/conf.d/apache2