# Apache never wants to run my python scripts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, python, apache2

Environment: Ubuntu 16, Apache 2.4

The last three times I tried to setup Apache to serve up Python I run into the same problem: Apache wants to let me download the script instead of running it and serving the html in the browser. Each time I figure it out, it turns out to be a combination of things I can never quite figure out.

For Simplicity:

I have the following shebang at the top of my file: `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`

Ran `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python`

Running `a2enmod python` returns `Module python already enabled`

Added all sorts of apache2.conf directives, none of them work:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     Options ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

According to [this link](https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts), this is all that should be required:

```
<Directory /srv/www/yoursite/public_html>
     Options +ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

And, this one works on another machine but not the present:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options +ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .py
     PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/index.py>
     Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

*Sorry if these apache2.conf's look like a mess, or have redundant lines, I was trying anything and everything.

Running `sudo a2enmod cgi` returns:

Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
Module cgid already enabled

The .py scripts are executable and are owned by www-data.

***Please HELP! This is so frustrating.*** What have I not tried? I want this to be the last time I have to do this. Every time I approach Apache, I approach it with fear; maybe it can smell it.

FYI: I have tried all of the (troubleshooting) steps at these sites (and many others):

https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138997/cgi-script-downloads-instead-of-running?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

[Why do I get error, Invalid command 'PythonHandler'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57505/why-do-i-get-error-invalid-command-pythonhandler?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://superuser.com/questions/174071/apache-serves-py-as-downloadable-file-instead-of-executing-it?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa (returns errror with their solution)

[Apache not handling python scripts (*.py) via browser](https://serverfault.com/questions/117103/apache-not-handling-python-scripts-py-via-browser)

***UPDATE***

So, here it is. I used test.py in /var/www/html/ so as not to change the source directory. Maybe something is wrong with my browser or the way I am accessing it?

```
$ ls -ltr /var/www/html/test.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    71 Mar 31 17:29 test.py

$ cat /var/www/html/test.py 
#!/usr/bin/python2

print("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print("hello")

$ grep -A 3 '<Directory /var/www/html/>'  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/html/>
     Options +ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>

$ ./test.py
Content-type:text/html


hello
```

I looked in the log files. Nothing odd in access.log, but error.log had an error about mismatched Python versions. According to this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/445179/python-version-mismatch-expected-2-6-5-found-2-6-6), it shouldn't be a problem. Regardless, I resolved the error by running:

```
$ apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ apt-get build-dep libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Proof: [Script downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IntLx.png)

Still no luck. I noticed there was an apache2 service running even after it was stopped. Thinking it may be a zombie process, I terminated all processes (it kept popping up), uninstalled and purged apache2, restarted and tried again.

Comment: what is the output of the script when run locally? what does access.log and error.log say?

Answer (score 2):

You've got this config:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     Options ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

This tells your apache server that files ending in `.cgi` should be handled as scripts. But you've named your script `test.py`.

Either rename your script to `test.cgi` or change your config to

```
     AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably close.

Here's the only thing I added to my stock Apache2 setup on Ubuntu

#### Note the perms

```
#ls -ltr  /var/www/html/python/char.py 
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 71 Mar 31 17:16 /var/www/html/python/char.py
```

#### Simple python2 script - make sure you do set the content-type

```
# cat  /var/www/html/python/char.py 
#!/usr/bin/python2

print("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
print("hello")
```

#### Runs fine locally

```
#/var/www/html/python/char.py 
Content-type:text/html


hello
```

#### Config

```
# grep -A 3 '<Directory /var/www/html/python/>'  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/html/python/>
     Options +ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

[image: Pic of Cgi running]

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback and time. Please see update. It's not looking good :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and tried all the troubleshooting steps that you did. The issue in my case was that I had the link to the cgi script in my php file and while my php server was running (using php -S localhost:8000), the cgi script was getting downloaded from the browser. But when I stopped the php server and then accessed the php script from browser using localhost/myScript.php (and hence the cgi from there on a button click), it worked.

So, if you are also running the php server, try stopping it and then run the php file from browser.